# How to extract multiple job url from a jobpost using python webscrapping

Tags: python, web-scraping, url, beautifulsoup, extract

[image: I would like to make a for loop and extract this URL-link for all the jobpost]

I have so far created the below code, to extract all the informations, but I cant figure out how to extract the link. I have tried with a for loop, but i get differents links. I really hope anyone can point me at the right direction.

```
def extract(page, tag):
    
url = f"https://www.jobindex.dk/jobsoegning?page ={page} &q ={tag}"
    
r = requests.get(url, headers)
    
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content.decode("utf-8"), "html.parser")
    
return soup
```

```
def transform(soup):
    divs = soup.find_all("div", class_="jobsearch-result")
    for item in divs:
        title = item.find_all("b")[0].text.strip()
        company = item.find_all("b")[1].text.strip()
        published_date = item.find("time").text.strip()
        summary = item.find_all("p")[1].text.strip()
        job_location = item.find_all("p")[0].text.strip()
        job_url = item.find_all("href")
        
        job = {
            "title" : title, 
            "company" : company,
            "published_date" : published_date,
            "summary" : summary,
            "job_location" : job_location,
            "Job_url" : job_url
        }
        joblist.append(job)

    return
```

Comment: @Qharr. Thanks its working. But I dont understand this code well, why are you saying "u="

Comment: `"u="` must be part of the `data-click` value, this was just an extra measure to help restrict the matched `a` tag elements. The job links have data-clicks like `data-click="/c?t=h1218058&ctx=w&u=21065603"` - on the rendered page. Slightly different in returned html but the `u=` is consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine an attribute = value css selector with contains `*` operator to target `onclick` attribute by a substring. Add to that selector list `:has` to specify element with matched `onclick` attribute must have immediate child `b` tag which restricts matches to those with the bold job title

```
[data-click*="u="]:has(> b)
```

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def extract(page, tag):
    
    headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
    
    url = f"https://www.jobindex.dk/jobsoegning?page={page}&q={tag}"
    
    r = requests.get(url, headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content.decode("utf-8"), "html.parser")
    
    return soup

def transform(soup):
    
    divs = soup.find_all("div", class_="jobsearch-result")
    
    for item in divs:
        title = item.find_all("b")[0].text.strip()
        company = item.find_all("b")[1].text.strip()
        published_date = item.find("time").text.strip()
        summary = item.find_all("p")[1].text.strip()
        job_location = item.find_all("p")[0].text.strip()
        job_url =  item.select_one('[data-click*="u="]:has(> b)')['href']
        
        job = {
            "title" : title, 
            "company" : company,
            "published_date" : published_date,
            "summary" : summary,
            "job_location" : job_location,
            "Job_url" : job_url
        }
        joblist.append(job)

    return

joblist = []
soup = extract(1, "python")
#print(soup)
transform(soup)
print(joblist)
```